# Slash or Backslash culture assistance

Tags: programming-languages, syntax

This isn't a technical question... I've been a programmer for years but I've never figured out a sure-fire way of remembering or "explaining to people over the phone" what the difference is between a forward slash and a backwards slash (/ or ).

I always end up saying "the one with the top bit going to the left/right" or vice versa.

I know it can't just be me that struggles with this pretty simple thing on a day to day basis, so has anyone got any methods or ways of remembering/explaining which you mean (I'm looking for a "stalactites hang on tightly to the ceiling" type analogy)

Also, this question is based purely on curiosity, I can live without the answer and if this is an inappropriate type of question please accept my apologies in advance if so.

Comment: Another spot for this type of question might be http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if they guess wrong, have them use the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the guy is running left to right (ie in the same direction you read text, so this is intuitive) then the forward slash is leaning forward, and the backslash is leaning back.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

Forward

- "It is what you see when you use your web-browser."
- "It's the same one most people make when writing."
- "Hold down shift and hit the question mark."
- "It points towards your left elbow."

Back:

- "You probably don't see this one much. Look between your "Enter" key and the "Backspace" key."